# Include current_user in ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I have an api-only rails application using `active_model_serializers` 0.10. I have a `current_user` attribute in my `ApplicationController` and am trying to access it from my serializers in order to restrict the data shown. I can do it by passing it to scope manually like this `ExerciseSerializer.new(@exercise, scope: current_user)`, but would like to have a general solution.

This is my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Response
  include ExceptionHandler

  serialization_scope :view_context

  # called before every action on controllers
  before_action :authorize_request
  attr_reader :current_user

  def check_access_rights(id)
    @current_user.id == id
  end

  def check_admin_rights
    if !@current_user.admin
      raise(ExceptionHandler::AuthenticationError, Message.unauthorized)
    end
  end

  private

  # Check for valid request token and return user
  def authorize_request
    @current_user = (AuthorizeApiRequest.new(request.headers).call)[:user]
  end

end
```

This is one of my serializers:

```
class ExerciseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :image_url, :note
  delegate :current_user, :to => :scope
  has_many :exercise_details

end
```

And this is how I present the objects:

```
  def json_response(object, status = :ok)
    render json: object, status: status
  end
```

When serializing I get the following error:

```
** Module::DelegationError Exception: ExerciseSerializer#current_user delegated to scope.current_user, but scope is nil:
```

When I try accessing the `current_user` from within the Serializer, I get the following error:

```
*** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<ExerciseSerializer:0x007ff15cd2e9c0>
```

And obviously scope is `nil`.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found it randomly after countless times unsuccessfully reading the offical docs : https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/rails-api-active-model-serializer

So here is the interesting part:

```rb
def current_user_is_owner
  scope == object
end
```

So current_user is saved in the `scope` variable **by default**, you don't need to add code in the controller to retrieve it.

Works in 0.10 and available since 0.08:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=scope&type=